# DeviceClient.GetTwinAsync() returns null?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I've created an IotHub, added a device, created a UWP app which uses the DeviceClient to successfully connect to the hub.
I can send telemetry as expected, and see the results in the Device Explorer.

However, when I try to fetch the device twin, I'm returned a null.

```
    var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, TransportType.Amqp);
    var twin = await deviceClient.GetTwinAsync();  // <<<< returns null
```

Are there any common scenarios that might cause this? Such as creating the IoTHub & device before Twin's were released. Or, not having set any desired properties before hand? Or, using the wrong shared access key? (etc.)

-John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: Twin capabilities requires the MQTT protocol, I was using AMQP.
I'm sure there is a mention of this buried somewhere, but after spinning on this for hours I can safely say it wasn't obvious.

On a more practical note: it would probably be helpful to throw an exception in the GetTwinAsync() method, if it is called on a connection that is not capable of supporting Twin.

Hopefully this post will help the next person.

-John

Comment: Yes, you are right. [At this time, device twins are accessible only from devices that connect to IoT Hub using the MQTT protocol.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins)

Comment: Thanks for confirming Rita. What about the second part of my observation, would it make sense to throw an exception?

Comment: Maybe. You can [open an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks) for this on github.